# Change a relation list without saving it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I want to change the list of a relation without saving it.

```
foo = Foo.first
foo.bars = []
foo.bars.reload
foo.bars
#=> [<Bar...>, ...]
```

I would like this code without doing a db transaction (except for the reload), It could be in a block or a gem, ...  But I do not want to do any rollback.

I know the code below work, but I need to keep the relation to be modify and validate in different functions, so it's not what I want.

```
foo = Foo.first
@bars = foo.bars
@bars = []
foo.bars
#=> [<Bar...>, ...]
```

If you need more information, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate that what actually do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another variable to clone the relation to use it later.

With two separate objects, you can modify one and use the relation of the second, then save the object you need.

```
# rails < 3.1
new_record = old_record.clone

#rails >= 3.1
new_record = old_record.dup
```

Comment: Sorry but when I said I know the code below works, It's to avoid this answer.`new_record` and `old_record` are not the same in an association. `new_records = foo.bars.dup` and `new_records = []` and `new_records.build` => `undefined method build for []:Array`. That why this solution doesn't suit me.